# SignalR-ObjC iOS app does not communicate with the server when deployed through iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, signalr

I'm writing an iOS app which uses SignalR to communicate with a web server.  I have created two clients for the web server, one is the iOS app, the other is an HTML client which I'm using for testing purposes.

I have two iPhone handsets which I'm using to test the iOS client. These are:

Handset a) The app was installed by debugging the app in XCode on the phone.

Handset b) The app was installed by creating an archive in XCode and installing it through iTunes.

The iOS app works correctly on handset a, but not on handset b. The HTML test client works correctly through the browser on both handsets.

Analysis of my web server logs shows that when handset b uses the iOS app, the web server does not pick up the initial connection at all, regardless of signal strength or length of time.

Is it possible that compiling the app into an archive through XCode is, in some way, not picking up the SignalR-ObjC libraries properly?  Is there some other step that I haven't found in the SignalR-ObjC documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that deploying to the phone via XCode deploys the Debug build, whereas deploying via iTunes deploys the Release build.  For reasons I'm yet to work out, the libraries that I am using were not packaged properly in the Release build.